# Moving to Konopka Signature VCL Controls

Tags: delphi, components

I have the source code for a Delphi project (unfortunately I am not sure what version this was developed in), that makes use of [Raize Components](http://www.raize.com/devtools/rzcomps/). Raize Components was acquired by Embarcadero and re-branded as Konopka Signature VCL Controls. So, as Raize is no longer available I can not compile this project's source.

I think the best solution is to switch out Raize for the newer Konopka, however I'm unsure how to do this. Is Konopka included with Delphi? Is it in the free edition? Can I buy it alone to use with the free edition? And, finally: Once I have Konopka will switching out the Raize controls be a straightforward process?

Comment: These are questions you should be asking the library's vendor.

Comment: @JerryDodge Good point. Initially I was under the impression that the vendor of Raize was no longer an active company (I didn't realize they had other products) so this hadn't occurred to me, but I'll keep that in mind for further inquiries. Thanks!

Comment: The "vendor" doesn't mean who made it, it means who is currently in charge of distribution / billing, etc. :-)

Comment: I upvoted this question because it is useful. The status of RaizeComponents is VERY unclear. The Raize.com mentions nothing about it. Sharing this kind of info with the community is useful. Therefore my +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Konopka Signature VCL Components are equivalent to the former Raize Components (actually they are the same), so a switch is basically the same as installing a new version of Raize Components.

The Konopka Components can be downloaded and installed via GetIt, although it is possible that they are only included in the latest version but probably not in the Starter Edition:

> The free Bonus Pack is only available to licensed owners of the
>   following products: RAD Studio, Delphi or C++Builder 10.1 Berlin
>   Professional, Enterprise and Architect editions.

I assume that this still holds true for the current 10.2 Tokyo versions.

Comment: Thank you for your informative and timely answer! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Having installed RAD Studio 10.2 I ran the GetIt Package Manager and installed the Konopka Signature VCL Components without needing to enter further licence info.

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience Probably outdated information:  _Updated: Jul 30, 2015_